# NSDate finding nearest date to today

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a sorted array of NSDates. Can someone help with how I can find the date in the array that is closest to the current date?

I need to get the index of the date closest so that I can scroll to that date in my tableview.

For example, if I have Jan 1 2013, Jan 6 2013, Jan 9 2013 and Jan 10 2013.  I want the index of Jan 6 2013.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:

I am trying this:

```
    NSTimeInterval interval = 0;
    NSUInteger indexOfDate;
    for (NSDate * date in m_arEventsSorted)
    {               
        if(abs([date timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]]) < interval)
        {
            interval = abs([date timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]]);
            indexOfDate = [m_arEventsSorted indexOfObject:date];
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only problem you have is the initial value of `interval`. Of course, it could be implemented better since your array is sorted but if you fix the initial value, it will work.

Comment: @LilMoke Sulthan is right; if the array is sorted you could improve performance using a *QuickSort*-like implementation; i.e. starting in the middle and moving up/down depending on their value.  This might not matter if you only have a small dataset, but would be worth the effort if you have a large dataset.

Comment: Or you can just set the initial interval to the difference of `now` and the first date and step processing whenever the interval starts increasing.

Comment: @Sulthan -- Correct.  Or, if the array is large, use a binary search.

Comment: If it's 11pm today, which date is closer? Tomorrow at 1am, or today at 7pm? If you want to go by date and ignore the time, you need to find the date closest but before your date and the date closest but after your date, and check the days to determine which one to return.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSDate` provides the `timeIntervalSinceNow` ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) method which returns a `NSTimeInterval` (a `typedef`'d `double`).  Simply use the `fabs()` function on this to find the smallest difference between each date and *now*.

Comment: I have updated my post with what I was trying to do, i think it is along the lines of what you said, but I am doing something foolish because it does not work as expected.  Can you look and comment on what I am missing.

Comment: @LilMoke You need to set `interval` to a very large value to start with, not `0`.

Comment: @LilMoke Sulthan has (correctly) edited my answer to change integer to `double`; therefore use `fabs()` instead of `abs()`.

Comment: Yes, interval was an issue.  I canhed it to a large number and it works correctly now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the timeIntervalSinceDate: function. Something like this (code not tested!):

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
double min = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
int minIndex = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < [array count]; ++i)
{
     double currentmin = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
     if (currentmin < min) {
           min = currentmin;
           minIndex = i;
     }
}
```

You can get the closest index from minIndex.

Comment: What role is ```[array objectAtIndex:0]``` playing. We are getting the ```min``` from the currentDate and using ```timeIntervalSinceDate```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
NSDate *closestDate;
for( NSDate *tempDate in dates ){
    NSInteger tempDateInterval = [tempDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    //to work with positive and negative time difference
    if( tempDateInterval < 0 ){
        tempDateInterval *= -1;
    }
    NSInteger closestDateInterval = [closestDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if( closestDateInterval < 0 ){
        closestDateInterval *= -1;
    }
    if( tempDateInterval < closestDateInterval ){
        closestDate = tempDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are many ways to skin the cat but my personal favourite skinning mechanism is to convert the date to epoch time so you know you're comparing oranges with oranges and just compare the dates as seconds.  This removes the issue of timezone problems too.

If you need to ensure you're picking the closest time to the date you may need to test the date with time's 00:00:01 and 23:59:59 and use the smallest result.

Use

```
long secondsToDate = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Answer (score 0):

based on Roland Keesom answer, this is how it worked for me:

```
 NSDate *currentDate = [[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"date"];
    int minIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < [objects count]; ++i)
    {
        NSDate *tempDate = [[objects objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"date"];
        NSInteger tempDateInterval = [tempDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
        if (tempDateInterval < 0) tempDateInterval *= -1;
        NSInteger closestDateInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
        if (closestDateInterval < 0) closestDateInterval *= -1;
        if( tempDateInterval < closestDateInterval ){
            currentDate = tempDate;
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
```

`minIndex` returns the index of the closest date to today in `objects` array.